# What's wrong with my ionic code or use of jsforce?

Tags: ionic2, salesforce

I am simply trying to subscribe a topic from salesforce in my ionic2 app it even allows rest api call but gives an error while subscribing topic:

```
 Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 405
```

here is the full code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import * as jsforce from "jsforce";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {



      var conn = new jsforce.Connection({

         loginUrl : 'https://login.salesforce.com'
      });

      var username = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
      var password = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

      conn.login(username, password, function(err, userInfo) {
        if (err) { return console.error(err); }

            console.log(conn.accessToken);
            console.log(conn.instanceUrl);

           //this part of code works
            conn.query("SELECT Id, Name FROM Account", function(err, result) {
              if (err) { return console.error(err); }
              console.log("total : " + result.totalSize);
              console.log("fetched : " + result.records.length);
            });

           // this part of codes doesn't work
            conn.streaming.topic("InvoiceStatementUpdates").subscribe(function(message) {
              console.log('Event Type : ' + message.event.type);
              console.log('Event Created : ' + message.event.createdDate);
              console.log('Object Id : ' + message.sobject.Id);
            });

            // logged in user property
            console.log("User ID: " + userInfo.id);
            console.log("Org ID: " + userInfo.organizationId);

      });




  }

}
```

Comment: 405 is Method Not Allowed. Looks like server side may not be configured for this..

Comment: @suraj  I had to enable cross origin sharing to run this app in browser otherwise it wouldn't allow "conn.login"  is this the reason why I am receiving 405